# Javascript form submit data not changing when submitting to Paypal

Tags: javascript, paypal

I have a form that will send the calculated amount to paypal.There are three radio button for this, I have no problem when selecting the first button, it will correctly calculate and send the correct data to paypal.The second and third is my problem, when I select either second and third, the previous value or data from first button will be send to paypal instead of the second or third value..This is a working form except that it does not send the proper amount to Paypal if I select the other radio button(#cat-both is working properly while #cat-loto and #cat-aerial were not submitting the correct value,the value of #cat-both is always send to paypal instead)
(This is a question answered by user Alain Nisam, [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35422562/javascript-calculate-values-based-on-checked-options/35426628?noredirect=1#comment58731333_35426628))

Html

```
<div>
    <p>$50.00 per class/person <br />Sign up for both for $90.00</p>
</div>
<div>
    <form id="paypal_submit_form" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" target="_blank" method="post">
        <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_cart" /> 
        <input name="upload" type="hidden" value="1" /> 
        <input name="charset" type="hidden" value="utf8" /> 
        <input name="business" type="hidden" /> 
        <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD" /> 
        <input name="custom" type="hidden" /> 
        <input name="amount" type="hidden" /> 
        <input name="first_name" type="hidden" /> 
        <input name="last_name" type="hidden" /> 
        <input name="address1" type="hidden" /> 
        <input name="city" type="hidden" /> 
        <input name="state" type="hidden" /> 
        <input name="zip" type="hidden" /> 
        <input name="email" type="hidden" /> 
        <input name="night_phone_b" type="hidden" /> 
        <input name="address_override" type="hidden" value="1" />
        <div id="paypal_prs" style="font-size: 12px;">
            <p>
                <input id="cat-both" checked="checked" name="cat" type="radio" value="90" /> 
                    <label for="cat-both">Both</label> 
                <input id="cat-aerial" name="cat" type="radio" value="50" /> 
                    <label for="cat-aerial">Aerial</label> 
                <input id="cat-loto" name="cat" type="radio" value="50" /> 
                    <label for="cat-loto">Lockout/Tagout</label>
            </p>
            <br /> Members:
            <select id="bal_number_of_members" style="font-size: 12px; padding: 3px;" name="number_of_members">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
            </select>
            <br /> Total Amount (Cost + Processing Fee): 
            <input style="width: 50px; margin-right: 10px; padding: 2px; padding-bottom: 1px; font-size: 12px;" name="tmp_total_amount" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="93" /> 
            <input id="bal_submit_btn" style="padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 12px; cursor: pointer;" type="button" value="Pay Here" /> 
            <input name="item_name_1" type="hidden" value="2016 Train-The-Trainer Workshops(AERIAL LIFTS &amp; LOCKOUT/TAGOUT)" /> 
            <input name="amount_1" type="hidden" value="90" /> 
            <input name="quantity_1" type="hidden" value="1" /> 
            <input name="item_name_2" type="hidden" value="Processing fee" /> 
            <input name="amount_2" type="hidden" value="0" /> 
            <input name="quantity_2" type="hidden" value="1" />
        </div>
        <input name="notify_url" type="hidden" value="http://some.org/tmp_ipn.php" /> 
        <input name="return" type="hidden" value="http://some.org/" /> 
        <input name="cancel_return" type="hidden" value="http://some.org/index.php?view=article&amp;id=278" /> 
        <input name="no_shipping" type="hidden" value="1" />
    </form>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getPayPalProcessingFee() {
         var qty = $('#paypal_submit_form select[name=number_of_members]').val();
         qty = parseInt(qty);


         var current_index = $("input[name=cat]:checked").attr('id');

         switch (current_index){
             case 'cat-both':

                return 3*qty;   

                break;
             case 'cat-aerial':

                return 1.8*qty;
                break;

             case 'cat-loto':

                return 1.8*qty;
                break;
             default:
                return 0;
         }
     }

  function trainthetrainerForm_calculateFee() {
        var fee = getPayPalProcessingFee();
        return fee;
    }
  function trainthetrainerForm_calculateItemAmount() {
    var qty = $('#paypal_submit_form select[name=number_of_members]').val();
    var current_val = $("input[name=cat]:checked").val();
        console.log(current_val);
    var amount = parseInt(qty) * current_val;
    amount = parseFloat(amount).toFixed(2);
    return amount;
  }


  function trainthetrainerForm_displayTotalAmount() {
    var amount = trainthetrainerForm_calculateItemAmount();
    console.log(parseFloat(amount));

    var totalamount = parseFloat(amount)+((parseFloat(amount)*0.029888888888889)+0.30);
    console.log(totalamount);
    totalamount = parseFloat(totalamount).toFixed(2);
    console.log(totalamount);

    $('#paypal_submit_form input[name=tmp_total_amount]').val(totalamount);

  }

  function submitTrainthetrainerForm() {
    var qty = $('#paypal_submit_form select[name=number_of_members]').val();
    $('#paypal_submit_form input[name=quantity_1]').val(qty);

    var totalAmount = 0;
    var amount = trainthetrainerForm_calculateItemAmount();
    var processingFee = trainthetrainerForm_calculateFee();

    totalAmount = amount + processingFee;

    $('#paypal_submit_form input[name=business]').val('shana@same.org');
    $('#paypal_submit_form input[name=amount]').val(totalAmount);
    $('#paypal_submit_form input[name=amount_2]').val(processingFee);
    $('#paypal_submit_form').submit();
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', $("#bal_number_of_members"), function() {
      trainthetrainerForm_displayTotalAmount();
    });
    $("#bal_submit_btn").click(function() {
      submitTrainthetrainerForm();
    });

   // trainthetrainerForm_displayTotalAmount();
  });
</script>
```

A working fiddle

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vbt1hr3o/1/)

**Update**

I found out that the input name="amount_1" value="90" does not change to the amount equivalent to

```
  var amount = trainthetrainerForm_calculateItemAmount();
```

Inside the

```
  submitTrainthetrainerForm()
```

function

form action

```
  action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
```

Any idea for this?

**Update**

Ok I think I almost solve this problem.The #cat-loto and #cat-aerial value already sending to paypal, but if I choose 2, 3, 4, 5 from the select #bal_number_of_members, the previous value will be multipled by the select #bal_number_of_members.Example, if I select 1 for cat-loto, it will send the proper number which is 51.79, how ever if I change and select the 2 for #bal_number_of_members, the tmp_value which is 103.59 will be multiplied by 2 and it will send to paypal the value of 103.59 multiplied by 2, it should be 103.59.

I updated the Javascript file based on user Alain Nisam answer

js file

```
 <script>
   function getPayPalProcessingFee() {
    var qty = $('#paypal_submit_form select[name=number_of_members]').val();
    qty = parseInt(qty);

    var current_index = $("input[name=cat]:checked").attr('id');

    switch (current_index){
        case 'cat-both':

            return 3*qty;   

            break;
        case 'cat-aerial':

            return 1.8*qty;
            break;

        case 'cat-loto':

            return 1.8*qty;
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
     }
  }

 function trainthetrainerForm_calculateFee() {
    var fee = getPayPalProcessingFee();
    return fee;
 }
 function trainthetrainerForm_calculateItemAmount() {
    var qty = jQuery('#paypal_submit_form    select[name=number_of_members]').val();
    var current_val = jQuery("input[name=cat]:checked").val();
    //console.log(current_val);
    var amount = parseInt(qty) * current_val;
    amount = parseFloat(amount).toFixed(2);
    return amount;
  }


 function trainthetrainerForm_displayTotalAmount() {
   var amount = trainthetrainerForm_calculateItemAmount();
   console.log(parseFloat(amount));
   var totalamount = parseFloat(amount)+ ((parseFloat(amount)*0.029888888888889)+0.30);
   console.log(totalamount);
   totalamount = parseFloat(totalamount).toFixed(2);
   console.log(totalamount);

   jQuery('#paypal_submit_form  input[name=tmp_total_amount]').val(totalamount);
  }

  function submitTrainthetrainerForm() {
   var qty = jQuery('#paypal_submit_form select[name=number_of_members]').val();
   jQuery('#paypal_submit_form input[name=quantity_1]').val(qty);

   var totalAmount = 0;
   var amount = trainthetrainerForm_calculateItemAmount();
   var processingFee = trainthetrainerForm_calculateFee();

   totalAmount = amount + processingFee;

   jQuery('#paypal_submit_form input[name=business]').val('shana@same.org');
   jQuery('#paypal_submit_form input[name=amount]').val(totalAmount);
   jQuery('#paypal_submit_form input[name=amount_2]').val(processingFee);
   jQuery('#paypal_submit_form').submit();
    return true;
  }

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', $("#bal_number_of_members"), function() {
     trainthetrainerForm_displayTotalAmount();
   });
   jQuery("#bal_submit_btn").click(function() {
    submitTrainthetrainerForm();
   });

   $(document).on('change',$('input[name="tmp_total_amount"]'),function(){
     $('input[name="amount_1"]').val($('input[name="tmp_total_amount"]').val()); 
     trainthetrainerForm_displayTotalAmount();
    });
  });
```

Comment: I see only one button, where are the other two?

Comment: @terrymorse, I mean input type="radio"

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35422562/javascript-calculate-values-based-on-checked-options/35426628?noredirect=1#comment58731333_35426628

Comment: @Alain Nisam, I found out that the fault here is in th input name="amount_1"  value="90".It seems that this need to be change what ever the value of   var amount = trainthetrainerForm_calculateItemAmount(); inside the submitTrainthetraineForm() function.Any idea?

Comment: @DanielleRoseMabunga - you can write the value you need to the hidden form field like this: $('input[name="amount_1"]').val(theNewAmount)

Answer (score 1):

Ok Danielle, this is my last answer- The only item I was unsure of is "quantity_2". It's set to 1 and I'm not sure what it's meant to represent.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<h2 class="contentheading" style="margin-top: 0px;">2016 “Train-The-Trainer” Workshops<br /><br /> AERIAL</h2>
<div>
    <p>$50.00 per class/person
        <br />Sign up for both for $90.00</p>
</div>
<div>
    <form id="paypal_submit_form" action="https://www.paypal.com/***" method="post">
        <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_cart" />
        <input name="upload" type="hidden" value="1" />
        <input name="charset" type="hidden" value="utf8" />
        <input name="business" type="hidden" value="shana@same.org" />
        <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD" />
        <input name="custom" type="hidden" />
        <input name="amount" type="hidden" />
        <input name="first_name" type="hidden" />
        <input name="last_name" type="hidden" />
        <input name="address1" type="hidden" />
        <input name="city" type="hidden" />
        <input name="state" type="hidden" />
        <input name="zip" type="hidden" />
        <input name="email" type="hidden" />
        <input name="night_phone_b" type="hidden" />
        <input name="address_override" type="hidden" value="1" />
        <div id="paypal_prs" style="font-size: 12px;">
            <p>
                <input id="cat-both" checked="checked" name="cat" type="radio" value="90" />
                <label for="cat-both">Both</label>
                <input id="cat-aerial" name="cat" type="radio" value="50" />
                <label for="cat-aerial">Aerial</label>
                <input id="cat-loto" name="cat" type="radio" value="50" />
                <label for="cat-loto">Lockout/Tagout</label>
            </p>
            <br /> Members:
            <select id="bal_number_of_members" style="font-size: 12px; padding: 3px;" name="number_of_members">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
            </select>
            <br /> Total Amount (Cost + Processing Fee):
            <input style="width: 50px; margin-right: 10px; padding: 2px; padding-bottom: 1px; font-size: 12px;" name="tmp_total_amount" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="93" />
            <input id="bal_submit_btn" style="padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 12px; cursor: pointer;" type="button" value="Pay Here" />
            <input name="item_name_1" type="hidden" value="2016 Train-The-Trainer Workshops(AERIAL LIFTS &amp; LOCKOUT/TAGOUT)" />
            <input name="amount_1" type="hidden" value="90" />
            <input name="quantity_1" type="hidden" value="1" />
            <input name="item_name_2" type="hidden" value="Processing fee" />
            <input name="amount_2" type="hidden" value="0" />
            <input name="quantity_2" type="hidden" value="1" />
        </div>
        <input name="notify_url" type="hidden" value="http://some.org/tmp_ipn.php" />
        <input name="return" type="hidden" value="http://some.org/" />
        <input name="cancel_return" type="hidden" value="http://some.org/index.php?view=article&amp;id=278" />
        <input name="no_shipping" type="hidden" value="1" />
    </form>
</div>
<div style="font-size: 11px; margin-top: 10px; color: red;">
    Additional 2.9% + $0.30 processing fee will be charged with all orders paid by credit card.
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <a style="font-size: 18px;" href="images/Flyer_2016.pdf" target="_blank">Download Order Form</a>
</div>
<p style="font-size: 14px;">
    <strong>Please fax or email the order form to the office.</strong>
</p>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('#bal_submit_btn').on('click',function(e){
  //Remove this in production and the form will continue to submit
  e.preventDefault();
  var theFee = getFee();
  var thePrice = getPrice();
  $('#paypal_submit_form input[name=business]').val('shana@same.org');
  $('#paypal_submit_form input[name=amount]').val(thePrice);
  $('#paypal_submit_form input[name=amount_2]').val(theFee);

  console.log( $('#paypal_submit_form').serializeObject() );
  return false;
})

$(document).on('change', $("#bal_number_of_members"), function(e) {
  return update();
});

function update(){
    var qty = $('#bal_number_of_members').val();
    var theFee = getFee();
    var thePrice = getPrice();
    var total = parseFloat(thePrice + theFee);
    $('#paypal_submit_form input[name=tmp_total_amount]').val(total);
    $('#paypal_submit_form input[name="amount_1"]').val(total);
    $('#paypal_submit_form input[name="amount"]').val(total);
    $('#paypal_submit_form input[name="amount_2"]').val(theFee);
    $('#paypal_submit_form input[name=quantity_1]').val(qty);
    return Math.round(total * 100)/100;
}

function getPrice() {
  var qty = $('#bal_number_of_members').val();
  var pricePerUnit = $("input[name=cat]:checked").val();
  var price = pricePerUnit * qty;
  return Math.round(price *100)/100;
}

function getFee() {
  var qty = $('#bal_number_of_members').val();
  var pricePerUnit = $("input[name=cat]:checked").val();
  var price = pricePerUnit * qty;
  var theFee = Math.round( ((price*0.029888888888889)+0.30) * 100)/100;
  return theFee;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    return update();
});

$.fn.serializeObject = function(){
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function() {
                if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                        if (!o[this.name].push) {
                                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                        }
                        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                } else {
                        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
                }
        });
        return o;
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated to use the correct field:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<h2 class="contentheading" style="margin-top: 0px;">2016 “Train-The-Trainer” Workshops<br /><br /> AERIAL</h2>
<div>
  <p>$50.00 per class/person
    <br />Sign up for both for $90.00</p>
</div>
<div>
  <form id="paypal_submit_form" action="https://www.paypal.com/***" method="post">
    <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_cart" />
    <input name="upload" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <input name="charset" type="hidden" value="utf8" />
    <input name="business" type="hidden" />
    <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD" />
    <input name="custom" type="hidden" />
    <input name="amount" type="hidden" />
    <input name="first_name" type="hidden" />
    <input name="last_name" type="hidden" />
    <input name="address1" type="hidden" />
    <input name="city" type="hidden" />
    <input name="state" type="hidden" />
    <input name="zip" type="hidden" />
    <input name="email" type="hidden" />
    <input name="night_phone_b" type="hidden" />
    <input name="address_override" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <div id="paypal_prs" style="font-size: 12px;">
      <p>
        <input id="cat-both" checked="checked" name="cat" type="radio" value="90" />
        <label for="cat-both">Both</label>
        <input id="cat-aerial" name="cat" type="radio" value="50" />
        <label for="cat-aerial">Aerial</label>
        <input id="cat-loto" name="cat" type="radio" value="50" />
        <label for="cat-loto">Lockout/Tagout</label>
      </p>
      <br /> Members:
      <select id="bal_number_of_members" style="font-size: 12px; padding: 3px;" name="number_of_members">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
      </select>
      <br /> Total Amount (Cost + Processing Fee):
      <input style="width: 50px; margin-right: 10px; padding: 2px; padding-bottom: 1px; font-size: 12px;" name="tmp_total_amount" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="93" />
      <input id="bal_submit_btn" style="padding: 3px 5px; font-size: 12px; cursor: pointer;" type="button" value="Pay Here" />
      <input name="item_name_1" type="hidden" value="2016 Train-The-Trainer Workshops(AERIAL LIFTS &amp; LOCKOUT/TAGOUT)" />
      <input name="amount_1" type="hidden" value="90" />
      <input name="quantity_1" type="hidden" value="1" />
      <input name="item_name_2" type="hidden" value="Processing fee" />
      <input name="amount_2" type="hidden" value="0" />
      <input name="quantity_2" type="hidden" value="1" />
    </div>
    <input name="notify_url" type="hidden" value="http://some.org/tmp_ipn.php" />
    <input name="return" type="hidden" value="http://some.org/" />
    <input name="cancel_return" type="hidden" value="http://some.org/index.php?view=article&amp;id=278" />
    <input name="no_shipping" type="hidden" value="1" />
  </form>
</div>
<div style="font-size: 11px; margin-top: 10px; color: red;">
  Additional 2.9% + $0.30 processing fee will be charged with all orders paid by credit card.
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 50px;">
  <a style="font-size: 18px;" href="images/Flyer_2016.pdf" target="_blank">Download Order Form</a>
</div>
<p style="font-size: 14px;">
  <strong>Please fax or email the order form to the office.</strong>
</p>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function trainthetrainerForm_calculateItemAmount() {
    var qty = jQuery('#paypal_submit_form select[name=number_of_members]').val();
    var current_val = jQuery("input[name=cat]:checked").val();
        //console.log(current_val);
    var amount = parseInt(qty) * current_val;
    amount = parseFloat(amount).toFixed(2);
    return amount;
  }


  function trainthetrainerForm_displayTotalAmount() {
    var amount = trainthetrainerForm_calculateItemAmount();
    console.log(parseFloat(amount));
    var totalamount = parseFloat(amount)+((parseFloat(amount)*0.029888888888889)+0.30);
    console.log(totalamount);
    totalamount = parseFloat(totalamount).toFixed(2);
    console.log(totalamount);

    jQuery('#paypal_submit_form input[name=tmp_total_amount]').val(totalamount);
    $('input[name="amount_1"]').val(totalamount);
  }

  function trainthetrainerForm_calculateFee() {
    var amount = trainthetrainerForm_calculateItemAmount();
    return (parseFloat(amount)*0.029888888888889)+0.30;
  }

  function submitTrainthetrainerForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var qty = jQuery('#paypal_submit_form select[name=number_of_members]').val();
    jQuery('#paypal_submit_form input[name=quantity_1]').val(qty);

    var totalAmount = 0;
    var amount = trainthetrainerForm_calculateItemAmount();
    var processingFee = trainthetrainerForm_calculateFee();

    totalAmount = amount + processingFee;

    jQuery('#paypal_submit_form input[name=business]').val('shana@same.org');
    jQuery('#paypal_submit_form input[name=amount]').val(totalAmount);
    jQuery('#paypal_submit_form input[name=amount_2]').val(processingFee);

console.log( $('form').serializeObject() );
return false;

    jQuery('#paypal_submit_form').submit();
    return true;
  }

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', $("#bal_number_of_members"), function() {
      trainthetrainerForm_displayTotalAmount();
    });
    jQuery("#bal_submit_btn").click(function(e) {
      submitTrainthetrainerForm(e);
    });

    trainthetrainerForm_displayTotalAmount();
  });

 $.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
}; 
</script>
```

Comment: still the value of #cat-both is sending instead of #cat-aerial, #cat-loto

Comment: Ok, I edited my last answer so that when you submit, it dumps ALL fields. I think it would be helpful to compare what is actually being posted.

Comment: Already did that.In developers console, console.log all correct values are correct.But I am confused why it does not send the correct value when sending to paypal

Comment: Using your code, the problem is in amount_1 when I select 1 for for cat-loto or cat-aerial.But when I select 2 or other numbers in drop down,number_1 dumps correct value

Comment: This code $(document).on('change',$('input[name="tmp_total_amount"]'),function(){
    $('input[name="amount_1"]').val($('input[name="tmp_total_amount"]').val())
  }) does not change the value.

Comment: I edited the code above by the the answer you provided, selecting 1 for either #cat-both,cat-loto,cat-aerial, will send a correct value to paypal however if I change the number_of_members value from the dropdown, the temp_value will be multiplied again by number selected from the number from number_of_memebers from the dropdown.So if I select 2 for the cat-both, the value wil be 185.68 which is correct, but if i submit it to paypal, the 185.68 will be multiplied again by 2.Same for the other cat names

Comment: Ok, I'm going to rewrite this whole thing since I feel like there is a lot of code that doesn't actually do anything or is redundant.

Comment: Did my final answer solve your problem? Can you accept it please?